# ES6 swap module at runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have api.js which loads either mock.js or server.js and exports it. The result is that based on server environment variables I can swap between backends.

**Problem is**, I want to do this **at Runtime** without affecting all the code that is already using the "api" of the mock.js and server.js modules.

I want my app to use either mock.js or server.js depending on connection status. The following code will work during initialization only, not runtime.

```
import server from './server'
import mock from './mock'

let backend = null
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && Math.random() > 0.5 ) {
  backend = mock
} else {
  backend = server
}

export default backend
```

Comment: Not certain what issue or Question is?

Comment: Yeah I'm confused, what is wrong with the code you have then?

Comment: @loganfsmyth say I wanted what the export is to change based on whether the current minute is odd or even... that's a silly example, what I really want is for it to change when the connection drops

Comment: @jfriend00 well the first page is authentication... so I would be logging in. Mock is using one password, and the server has another one.

Comment: @jfriend00 its a module... i'm importing it and then using some methods. Logan figured out the issue.. it was with the way I was exporting which statically locks it... at least with babel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take advantage of ES6 live binding if you want, e.g.

```
import server from './server';
import mock from './mock';

export { backend as default };

let backend = server;

setInterval(() => {
    backend = Math.random() > 0.5 ? mock : server;
}, 1000);
```

which will change the default export randomly every second.

In ES6, imported variables are live references to the variable in the module that exports the value, so you can just

```
import backend from "./api";
```

and the `backend` value will change over time.

Specifically in your case, changing

```
export default backend;
```

to

```
export { backend as default};
```

is critical, as the first doesn't work because it is short for

```
const uniqueTempVal = backend;
export { uniqueTempVal as default };
```

which as you can see means reassigning `backend` later does not affect the exported value.

Comment: But, if routes are already registered based on either mock or server, then this won't do anything to just swap those variables after the fact.  This is just a wild guess.  We can't actually know the answer to the question until we understand what the OP is doing with the mock or server module once it is loaded.

Comment: You mean if something is caching a reference to a specific backend, rather than referencing back to the import every time? I guess I was assuming they were consistently referencing the import. Like `backend.query("/foo")` or whatever.

Comment: We need to see how the OP is using this result before we could possibly know what would or would not work.  You made a guess based on an assumption.  Might be right, might be wrong.  We should make the OP clarify what they're doing with this module and make it into a question that doesn't requiring guessing or assuming.

Comment: Given the information we have, this is the right approach. There could certainly be other mitigating factors that we don't know yet, clearly.

Comment: BTW< what is "ES6 live binding"?  The assignment to `backend` in your `setInterval()` could be done in ES3.

Comment: @jfriend00 My issue is I was using `export default backend` instead of export `default { backend as default}`. It makes a huge difference. In the former case it will be undefined or hard set, in the latter it's live.

Comment: @jfriend00 "In ES6, imported variables are live references to the variable in the module that exports the value"

Comment: Any variable that holds a pointer to an object is a "live reference" (to use your term) in Javascript.  Are you implying there's a new type of variable in ES6 that holds references that didn't exist in ES5?

Comment: @jfriend00 The `import`/reference part is the important bit, not the variable part. Most people assume `import foo from "foo"; ` behaves like `var foo = require('foo');`, but that is incorrect., `foo` isn't a separate variable that takes the current value of the export at import time, it is actually a transparent reference to the variable in the imported file. That means if the export is reassigned, the file importing that variable will get the new value transparently, rather than somehow having to re-import it.

Comment: @loganfsmyth - Can you point to any reference material on this new kind of variable in ES6?

Comment: It's the "indirect binding" defined by `CreateImportBinding`: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-createimportbinding and handled in `GetBindingValue`: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-module-environment-records-getbindingvalue-n-s

Answer (score 1):

Put the object you want to export in a property of the exported object:

```
import server from './server'
import mock from './mock'

let backend = { api: null };
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && process.env.NODE_MOCK === true) {
  backend.api = mock;
} else {
  backend.api = server;
}

export default backend;
```

Now just use the `api` property in the importing code.